# jQuery - Find string and prepend string to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I go about searching for a specific string in a div, then prepending or replacing the string with something else using jQuery/JavaScript?

For Example:

> "We provide Professional Indemnity,
>   Public Liability, Employer's
>   Liability, Office and a whole host of
>   other specialist insurance covers for
>   a wide range of professions."

Replace the string `Liability` with `something Liability something`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`$('div').text( $('div').text().replace(/Liability/, 'something Liability something') );`

http://jsfiddle.net/JzPyW/

Comment: Nice solution. Super small performance improvement would be to store $('div') in a variable like $div.

Comment: why to use .text() not .html() ??

Comment: @Praveen, you could, I suppose it depends on whether or not the `.replace()` is likely to change something tag-internal or not. My answer was more a general direction, but with no initial code from the OP, you shouldn't really get caught up in the specifics.

Comment: Of course the regex can also be changed to `/.../g` if more than one change needs to occur.